# Using a list of possible diagnosis (look up table) to find out a specific diagnosis in a series of clinical narratives

Tags: python, list, loops, match, series

I have a dataset of clinical narratives from which I want to extract diagnosis of cancer.

This is an example of the narratives (each string is a row on the dataset (most narratives have just one diagnosis but other have multiple.

```
['Simple tubular carcinoma and solid carcinoma of the mammary gland', 'Sebaceous adenomas', 'Splenic haemangiosarcoma', 'mammary adenoma and mixed mammary carcinoma' 'Panniculitis']
```

So, in order to detect the diagnosis in each row, I use a look up table like this:

```
['Solid carcinoma', 'tubular carcinoma' 'adenoma', 'hemangiosarcoma', 'mammary adenoma', 'mixed mammary carcinoma']
```

So, what I need to do is to loop the look up table over each narrative in order to find out which of the diagnoses of the look up table are on each clinical narrative.

I have tried this.

```
def t(x):
    for item in [Tumour_list]:
        if item in Narratives_series :
            return item
    return False

print(Narratives_series)
print(Narratives_series.apply(t))
```

Expecting this:
[image]

But so far, has been no possible. I´m still new on Python :-)
Jose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
diagnoses = ['Solid carcinoma', 'tubular carcinoma', 'adenoma', 'haemangiosarcoma', 'mammary adenoma', 'mixed mammary carcinoma']

narrative_diagnoses = {}
for narrative in narratives:
        narrative_diagnoses[narrative] = []
        for diagnosis in diagnoses:
                if diagnosis.lower() in narrative.lower():
                        narrative_diagnoses[narrative].append(diagnosis)
```

This creates a dictionary where the keys are the narratives and the values are a list of all the diagnoses found in the narrative.

Comment: I think I didn´t explain myself good enough (apologies). The main problem is that I have all those narratives (more than 100000) in a column and all the diagnosis (1000) in other column. I want Python to look over the narratives with all the diagnosis list and return matches in a third column. In other words, if we consider the example, the desired result would be that when Python reads the narrative with "Simple tubular carcinoma and solid carcinoma of the mammary gland"  it returns "solid carcinoma" and "tubular carcinoma". Hope this makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my code based on your comment. But one question is what happens when there are more than two diagnoses in a narrative, for example,  for the narrative: "Mammary adenoma and mixed mammary carcinoma" do you want to extract "adenoma" as a single diagnosis itself or do you want just the two diagnoses you show in the table. My code outputs this for this narrative: ['adenoma', 'mammary adenoma', 'mixed mammary carcinoma']

Comment: Thanks a lot! The result is great. Your question is very appropiate and I'm not really sure which is better because in this case the output for "Mammary adenoma" is "Mammary adenoma" + "adenoma" and it should be (if possible) only "Mammary adenoma" because there is just one diagnosis and not two. Howerver, it would be fine for narratives like "mammary adenoma and skin unnespecified adenoma". Maye I have to reduce the reference list and remove generic terms. However, your code is a great first step. What I don't get is this line : narrative_diagnoses[narrative]. Thanks 